# Change of variable in multivariable integrals - not injective function and inverse transformation not analytical

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

I have an integral of a function that depends on multiple variables:

$\int_\Omega f(x,y,z)dzdydx=1$

where $x, y$, and $z$ can take values from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Now each of the variables are functions of other three variables $u, v,$ and $w$.

$x = x(u,v,w), y=y(u,v,w), z=z(u,v,w)$

I know that the variables $u, v $ and $w$ can take values from $0$ to $1$, from $0$ to $\infty$ and from $0$ to $\infty$ respectively. However, these functions are not injective and the inverse transformation

$(u,v,w)=(u(x,y,z),v(x,y,z),w(x,y,z))$

is not analytical. My question is, what is the integrand that I have to use in order to do this integral using the variables $(u,v,w)$? In other words, in the following equation,

$\int_\Omega f(x,y,z)dzdydx=\int_\Gamma g(u,v,w)dudvdw$

How can I find the function $g(u,v,w)$?

Comment: $$\int_\Omega f(x,y,z)\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx=\int_\Gamma f(x(u,v,w),y(u,v,w),z(u,v,w))|\det \mathbf J|\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv\,\mathrm dw$$where $\mathbf J$ is the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) for the transformation.

Comment: That would be the case when the function is injective. Originally, that is what I did in the first place, but then I realized that, doing the integral just multiplying by the Jacobian, the value of the integral was different from the original value 1.